# Unable to Customize EditForm.aspx with Document Sets in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, content-type

I give...I am hoping someone has a good answer.

I create a content type based on a Document Set (called A).  I create a document library and allow this new custom content type to be added to the library.  I add one column (say Car Phone) to the new content type(A).

I want to be able to edit the EditForm.aspx to add some text or javascript.

However, if I do anything to the editform.aspx through SharePoint designer it completely ignores any custom fields on my content type A.  Now, when selecting the item, and selecting edit i do not see my Car Phone Property.
This occurs only when i do anything to the editform.aspx that exists in the document library.  Just copying to a new name and setting as the default edit form it ignores my custom properties on the content type A>

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently an issue on the version for SharePoint 2010 that we were using.  It is documented that attributes on document sets are not able to be edited with the version of SharePoint that we had installed.

We updated the version of SharePoint we were using and this resolved our problem.  We migrated to the version prior to sp1 and that was the resolution.